# Send email with a custom designed template

Tags: magento-1.7

I've installed a gateway module which works through a site-wide based payment.  The customer pays the order inside the store. I know all payment statuses for any transaction, for example, 0 = "Order received", 1 = "Checking payment", 2 = "Authorized" and others.

I would like to send an email to the customer (with Bcc to the store administrator) to notice that the payment hasn't been authorized.

Can I create a custom email template from admin dashboard and send an email using that new custom template? I would like also to put a link on the message which allows the customer to try to make a payment again.

Comment: You might be able to get better answers on [magento.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post there!